# Testing NSImages for equality

Tags: nsimage, nsimageview, equatable

I have multiple identically-configured NSImageView objects in an NSPanel, all with drag-and-drop mode enabled. I’d like to cross-check the contained images to flag duplicates. But when I drop a single small gif or jpeg onto two of the controls, the obvious test always fails:

```
@IBOutlet weak private var picA: NSImageView!
@IBOutlet weak private var picB: NSImageView!

if picA.image == picB.image
  {
    //  Do some things.
  }
```

Am I misunderstanding what equality means for NSImage? Is there another way?